# how to write query string for webrick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

My rails application requires few values to be specified in the text box.
My web page contains few text boxes .How can i specify the values of these text boxes in the url as query string while using webrick?can any one help, am new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your url looks like this: `localhost:3000/Accounts/1/edit?value1=A&value2=B` and you want to put those in text boxes you must create some instance variables in the controller, and then reference them in the view.

Controller Action:

```
def edit
   @value1 = params[:value1]
   @value2 = params[:value2]
end
```

View:

```
<%= text_box_tag :value1, @value1 %>
<%= text_box_tag :value2, @value2 %>
```

If you followed my example, the first text box would display A and the second B.

Note that the webserver has no effect on this behavior.  webrick, apache, mongrel, thin, etc... will all do this.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it very well.i got it.